# Class level, instance level and local ThreadLocals

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand how class level thread locals makes sense. Being associated with thread, we need thread locals to be shared among different instances and classes across that thread. So we need to make them class level. If we want to share thread local across different instances of same class, we can make them `private static`. If we want to share thread local across different classes, we can make them `public static`.

**Q0.** correct me if am wrong with above

My doubts are about instance scoped (`non-static`) thread locals and local (defined inside some method) thread locals:

**Q1.** Is there any valid use case for instance scoped (`non-static`) thread locals?
**Q2.** Is there any valid use case for local (defined inside some method) thread locals?
**Q3.** Are instance scoped (`non-static`) thread locals deleted when an instance is garbage collected?
**Q4.** Are local (defined inside some method) thread locals deleted when method returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThreadLocal` when implemented correctly as a static variable acts essentially as an instance variable for all threads that have access to it. Even though there's a single `ThreadLocal` variable, the mechanism makes it so that each thread has its own instance of the value in it.

Therefore

Q1. No, it doesn't make sense to have an instance scoped `ThreadLocal`. This doesn't mean you *couldn't* write code that would use an instance scoped `TL`, but you would need to keep track (in your developer mind) of both the *instance* and the *thread* being used for correct functionality, that even if you would find a use case that the code would solve, there would be a lot better way to handle it.

Q2. No. As a local variable can never have more than a single thread access it, it would not differ from a regular local variable.

Q3. The `ThreadLocal<>` wrapper becomes unreachable, but the actual variable is still contained in the thread's map, as you correctly said. This causes a resource/memory leak, as it can't be cleared until the thread stops.

Q4. Same as with Q3, if you lose the wrapper reference, it's an instant leak. If you assign the reference somewhere, it's just weird programming. A method local `ThreadLocal` variable would be extremely worrying code.

The class is not something you'd want to use too much anyway in modern code (or even older code), and it's not compatible with reactive programming, but if you do use it the usage is straight-forward. A single `ThreadLocal` most easily implemented as a class level variable.

Comment: I believe all types of (class, instance and local) thread local variables are created inside [`Thread.threadLocals` map](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java#L182). So, when we return from a method, isnt there still an active reference to local thread-local instance accessible from [`Thread.threadLocals.tables` array](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#L327), preventing GC?

Comment: Do you mean to say GC will be prevented for local thread local variiables, as I suggested in my comment? But in your asnwer to Q3, you said regular GC applies. Does that mean, preventing GC of local thread locals is according to regular GC behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> **Q2.** Is there any valid use case for local (defined inside some method) thread locals?

First, lets's just be clear. If you say "a local `Foobar`" (for any `class Foobar`), then it's not entirely clear what you are talking about. *Variables* can be "class level" (i.e., `static`) or "instance level," or "local;" but a `Foobar` instance is *not* a variable. The variables in a Java program can only *refer* to `Foobar` instances that are allocated on the heap. It's very easy, and very common to have more than one variable in a program refer to the same instance.

`ThreadLocal` is a class, and instances of `ThreadLocal` are objects on the heap. The same `ThreadLocal` object could be referenced by a `static ThreadLocal` variable and also, at the same time, referenced by local variables in one or more threads.

When you say "a local `ThreadLocal`," you *could* be talking about a local *variable* that holds a reference to a `ThreadLocal` instance that is shared with other threads, **-OR-** you could be talking about a `ThreadLocal` instance that is *only* referenced by one local variable. The second case would not make any sense because that instance could not be shared by multiple threads.

---

> **Q1.** Is there any valid use case for instance scoped (non-static) thread locals?

Maybe so, but I would call it a "[code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)." (That is, a reason to look closely at the code and see whether it could be better organized.) I *personally* would never use `ThreadLocal` in new code. The only times I have ever used it is, while porting older, single-threaded code into a multi-threaded system; and when I did it, the variables in question always were `static` (i.e., class level) variables.

I *personally* try never to use `static` in new code except in cases where some function is clearly labelled as returning a reference to a "singleton object."

---

> **Q3., Q4.** [...when are instances deleted...]?

An instance will be *eligible* to be deleted when there is no "live" variable in the program that refers to it. One way that can happen is if the only variable that refers to it is a local variable of some function, and that function returns. A second way it can happen is if the only variable that refers to the instance is assigned to refer to some other instance. A third way is if the only references to it are from instance variables of other objects, and all of those other objects are themselves, eligible to be deleted.

In most Java implementations, the instance will not be immediately deleted when it becomes eligible for deletion.  The actual deletion will happen some time later. When, depends on the strategies employed by the JRE's *[garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science))* and on the patterns of object use by the program.

Comment: "The second case would not make any sense because that instance could not be shared by multiple threads." - but anyway, the thread locals can never be shared by multiple threads. Also I know how garbage collection works. But thread locals are stored in `threadlocals` map variable of `Thread` class which is of type `ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap`. So I was thinking if there is no active reference to specific thread local variable, will it be automatically removed from this `threadlocals` map automatically.

Comment: @anir, You misunderstand. Suppose you have `ThreadLocal<Foo> foo=new ThreadLocal<>();` I was speaking of the single, shared `ThreadLocal` object, not of the several thread-specific `Foo` objects to which it refers. A `ThreadLocal` object is a _collection_ —just like `ArrayList` or `HashMap`, except that the objects in the collection are implicitly selected by the ID of the calling thread instead of being explicitly selected by a given "index" or "key."